# Don't automatically adjust xlim, ylim for certain plot items in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

When using matplotlib to draw a bunch of lines, the axes limits are automatically adjusted to fit all plots into the visible range.
Now, I would like to add a number of lines that are purely meant for orientation, and that do not necessarily need to be in the visible range at full size. Is it possible to tell matplotlib *not* to adjust `xlim`, `ylim` for certain plot objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn autoscaling off using the state-machine[(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.autoscale) or OO [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.autoscale) interfaces.

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.plot(arange(15))
plt.draw() # it will re-scale here
ax.autoscale(False)
ax.plot(arange(15) ** 2)
ax.draw() # will not rescale
```